# Array index out of bounds error C#

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

i have this code that im getting error and, and cant understand why im getting the error. the code is as following: im using two arrays a string and a double(data values with their corresponding tinestamp). But for some reason im getting error that:  index out of bounds error   on this line:

```
     getSelectedItemsObj.arrayOfTimeStamp        = GetItemData(parameterName[counter], fromTime, toTime).arrayOfTimeStamp;
```

If i remove this line and only use arrayOfValue the code works fine, but i need both

.......... Thanks for the fast replies, here is how GetItemData is set up

```
 public CustomDataType GetItemData(string parameterName, string fromTime, string toTime)
    {

        getWeatherItemObj = new CustomDataType();
        // get the parameter ID
        prameterID = GetParameterInfo(parameterName).ParameterID; 
        //get the nr of items to size value arrays
        tableSize = GetTableSize(parameterName, fromTime, toTime, prameterID);
        getWeatherItemObj.arrayOfValue      = new double[tableSize];            
        getWeatherItemObj.arrayOfTimeStamp  = new string[tableSize];
        counter = 0;
        try
        {
            using (conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))// create and open a connection object
            {
                // 1. create a command object identifying the stored procedure
                 cmd = new SqlCommand("GetItemData", conn);
                // 2.Let the command object know we will execute a stored procedure
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                // 3. add the 3 parameters to command, so the can be passed to the stored procedure                  
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ParameterName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value    = parameterName;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@FromTime", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value                = fromTime;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ToTime", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value                  = toTime;
                //open connection
                conn.Open();
                // execute the command
                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        getWeatherItemObj.arrayOfValue[counter]         = (double)reader["MeasurementValue"];
                        getWeatherItemObj.arrayOfTimeStamp[counter]     = reader["MeasurementDateTime"].ToString();                          
                        counter++;
                    }
                } 
                //close connection
                reader.Close();            
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Connection failed");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }           
        return getWeatherItemObj;
    }






 class CustomDataType
{
    public double[] arrayOfValue;
    public string[] arrayOfTimeStamp;

}

public CustomDataType GetSelectedtemsData(string[] parameterName, string fromTime, string toTime)
    {
        numberOfParameters = parameterName.Length;//Get the number of given parameters
        tableSize = 0;
        for (counter = 0; counter < numberOfParameters; counter++)
        {
            tableSize = tableSize + GetItemData(parameterName[counter], fromTime, toTime).arrayOfTimeStamp.Length;               
        }

        getSelectedItemsObj = new CustomDataType();

        getSelectedItemsObj.arrayOfValue        = new double[tableSize];
        getSelectedItemsObj.arrayOfTimeStamp    = new string[tableSize];
        for (counter = 0; counter < tableSize; counter++)
        { 
            getSelectedItemsObj.arrayOfValue            = GetItemData(parameterName[counter], fromTime, toTime).arrayOfValue;
            getSelectedItemsObj.arrayOfTimeStamp        = GetItemData(parameterName[counter], fromTime, toTime).arrayOfTimeStamp;

        }
        return getSelectedItemsObj;
    }
```

Comment: what line of code throws exception?

Comment: Perhaps because `counter` > Length of `parameterName`?  Do you honestly think it is possible to debug a problem when you don't even show where data comes from (such as `parameterName`) or what most of your code is even doing (i.e., `GetItemData`)?

Comment: Please provide: the error complete message, the error's stack trace, and the code of the method highest on the error's stack trace which you wrote (might be `arrayOfTimeStamp`).

Comment: i think the problem is you are incrementing `counter` up to `tableSize`, which does not look like it will be anything based on the number or parameters.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal: The error line is in a loop enforced by the constraint `counter < tableSize`.  There's no indication that `tableSize` should be less than `numberOfParameters`, unless `GetItemData` always returns a `1` or `0`.  Furthermore, the actual error could be inside the `arrayOfValue` setter, the `arrayOfValue` getter, or `GetItemData` method.

Comment: Just an FYI instead of tableSize = tableSize + GetItemData(parameterName[counter], fromTime, toTime).arrayOfTimeStamp.Length; -- You can do tableSize += GetItemData(parameterName[counter], fromTime, toTime).arrayOfTimeStamp.Length;

Comment: I had that initially, i just changed to code to this for seaching the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following:

```
public CustomDataType GetSelectedtemsData(string[] parameterName, string fromTime, string toTime)
{
    CustomDataType tempObj;     // *Rename this variable*
    List<double> valueList = new List<double>();
    List<string> timeStampList = new List<string>();

    for (counter = 0; counter < parameterName.Length; counter++)
    {
        tempObj = GetItemData(parameterName[counter], fromTime, toTime);
        valueList.AddRange(tempObj.arrayOfValue);
        timeStampList.AddRange(tempObj.arrayOfTimeStamp);
    }

    getSelectedItemsObj = new CustomDataType();
    getSelectedItemsObj.arrayOfValue = valueList.ToArray();
    getSelectedItemsObj.arrayOfTimeStamp = timeStampList.ToArray();

    return getSelectedItemsObj;
}
```

I was going to try it your way, but once I realized you were pulling each parameterName 3 times, and the second loop would need an inner loop (since you would need to iterate through each index in each GetItemData), and that my fix would have resulted in multiple copies of the same data anyways; I decided to rebuild the method using two `List`.

If this does not solve your issue then I will need the complete error message, the stack trace from the error message, and the code of the top most method on the error stack.

Note: There are a number of additional optimizations which may help you like:

- You may also want to update `GetItemData` to also use `List` instead of arrays so you can skip the `tableSize = GetTableSize(parameterName, fromTime, toTime, prameterID);` line.
- You may want to change `CustomDataType` so `arrayOfValue` and `arrayOfTimeStamp` are not arrays.  Then, instead of passing a `CustomDataType` out you could pass a `CustomDataType[]` or even `List<CustomDataType>`.

Comment: Thanks a million times!!, im new to the .net environment so im not comfortable with Lists yet. But the realy strange thing to me was that GetItemData was returning two same size arrays from a database procedure, and still got that error. Works fine with List now, again many thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in how you're treating your counter. If you remove the timestamp stuff, the counter never really gets modified so it all appears to work, but if you have the timestamp stuff in there, then your for loop initializer looks like this:

```
for (counter = 0; counter < tableSize; counter++)
```

where `tableSize` is ultimately greater than `parameterName[].Length`. Since later you're calling `parameterName[counter]`, counter will be out of bounds. You need to make sure that you're never attempting to access something in `parameterName[]` by an index that is not legal within that array.

*Edit:*
Another possibility, if removing **only** that line removes the error, is that the return of

```
GetItemData(parameterName[counter], fromTime, toTime).arrayOfTimeStamp;
```

is larger than the specified array allocated in

```
getSelectedItemsObj.arrayOfTimeStamp    = new string[tableSize];
```

In order to make such a determination, you would need to post the code to that method as well.

Comment: As I noted on Tyrsius's answer, it seems to me the OP said it works if he removes the `arrayOfTimeStamp` line.  Since both the `arrayOfValue` and the `arrayOfTimeStamp` lines contain `parameterName[counter]` I expect that this is not the solution to the OP.  I do agree that this is an issue which will need to be fixed.

Comment: @Trisped: Given that OP has chosen not to share the inner workings of GetItemData with us, this is the best answer that can be offered with the data available. I'll post an edit with an alternative possibility, but it's shear conjecture at that point.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is right here:

```
for (counter = 0; counter < tableSize; counter++)
{ 
     getSelectedItemsObj.arrayOfValue            = GetItemData(parameterName[counter], fromTime, toTime).arrayOfValue;
     getSelectedItemsObj.arrayOfTimeStamp        = GetItemData(parameterName[counter], fromTime, toTime).arrayOfTimeStamp;    
}
```

Your `counter` size is being incremented based on `tableSize`, but its being used as if its based on the size of `parameterName`. Nothing in your code enforces this assumption, so as soon as `tableSize` is larger than `parameterName`, you will get the error you are seeing.

Comment: Seems to me he said it works if he removes the `arrayOfTimeStamp` line.  Since both the `arrayOfValue` and the `arrayOfTimeStamp` lines contain `parameterName[counter]` I expect that this is not the solution to the OP.  I do agree that this is an issue which will need to be fixed.

Comment: @Trisped If I had any idea what `GetItemData` did, I could comment on that. But he didn't post it, so your guess is as good as mine.